# Answer flag disputed, think it needs a second look

Tags: support, disputed-flags

I was looking at my flag history (as I do periodically do to check that I'm doing things properly) and saw one of my flags disputed.

I reviewed and flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24055560/1590950) as "Not an answer". It is a thank you and a copy-paste of the answer that helped the answer's author. I think whoever reviewed the flag missed it and it needs a second pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Not An Answer" flags get funneled into the Low Quality Review queue for the community to review. The [flag was reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4986884) and the answer received 3 x Looks Good and 1 x Recommend Deletion votes, which in turn Disputed your flag.

I agree with your assessment that this is Not An Answer (with a thank you answer and copy of code in another answer) and I have now deleted it.

Comment: Thanks bluefeet. I can see how it got through. It only becomes apparent if you open the question itself and read through the other answers.

Comment: That's why I'm thinking it was disputed, the review queue is only presented with the flagged answer and the question, not the other answers.

Comment: @indivisible - In a case like this, I'd recommend using an "other" flag and describing exactly what's wrong with the answer. That greatly reduces the chance that people will miss what you saw. "not an answer" flags don't provide a lot of context, so not everyone will catch what you did.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have left a comment on the answer but I didn't really think it warranted escalation at the time. I'll make sure to leave explicit comments in not so clear cut cases in the future for the reviewers.